# inserting commas and parenthesis in single and multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `77777 44444 4444 456.52`
and I want to make `('77777', '44444', '4444', '456.52')`.

Is there key/software/program where I can insert commas and parenthesis in certain place as needed.I would really appreciate your help because doing it manually is awful.

Comment: Try using Excel formulas: `[7777][="'" & A1 & "'"]`

Comment: Can you better explain the problem? *Where* do you have those numbers?  Are they in a string variable?  In a column in a table?  Are they really in four columns?

Comment: I know how to use in Excel. Those numbers are in one column. It is a string  . I have tables in oracle and I have to put these values as where condition. Since the list might be long and I have to type all the criteria meeting values . For example  select * from table_a where values in ('77777', '44444', '4444', '456.52'). You can imagine my frustration since my values are in 77777 44444 4444 456.52 format.

Comment: You can put it in notepad++ (or something similar) then use a regex find/replace... would work well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of phrasing the query as:

```
where values in ('77777', '44444', '4444', '456.52')
```

You can phrase it as:

```
where ' '||values||' ' like ' %77777% ' or
      ' '||values||' ' like ' %44444% ' or
      ' '||values||' ' like ' %4444% ' or
      ' '||values||' ' like ' %456.52% ';
```

Use `and` instead of `or` if it has to match all the values.

Or, you could use regular expressions, if you are only looking for one value:

```
where regexp_like(' '||values||' ', ' 77777|44444|4444|456.52 ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your line of numbers in NotePad++ or any test editor that allows regex search:

Find: `([\d]+\.?[\d]+)`

Replace: `'$1',`